# Rails formatting BigDecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formatting, bigdecimal

My question it's simple (I think):

In Rails I have custom datetime format function called **l**, there are a equivalent for BigDecimal?

Example that I want:

```
index.html.erb

<%= l bill.date, format: :od %>
<%= ? bill.total_amount, format: :o2d %>
<%= ? bill.tax_amount, format: :o2d %>
```

I want to represent BigDecimal as currency with money symbol, but now I use:

```
<%= number_to_currency bill.total_amount, unit: '&euro;', separator: ',', delimiter: '.', format: '%n %u' %>
```

It's seems dirty?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all this question seems to be related to ruby and not to rails in particular. Second: unless you provide an example of what you try to do I don't think anyone will be able to help you

Comment: Ivaylo: It's not related with Ruby, it's related with Rails because **l** function is in it.

Comment: Ahh sorry. It is very easy to miss that part of the question.

Comment: Ivaylo: Are you kidding me? My English does not allow me to capture the irony.

Comment: no I am being serious and I really apologize. I am not a big expert in rails and I did not know about `l`.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'm losing in translation.

Comment: Jon, Dominik: I know how to implement helpers, and maybe I'm don't understand how to ask better, but have Rails yet this function with I18n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ruby gem will help you.

https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

Probably you have to implement your own view helper, and you should implement in it as like follows.

```
money = Money.new(1000, "USD")
money.cents => 1000
money.symbol => $    

def money_helper(money)
  "#{money.symbol}#{money.cents}" 
end

<%= money_helper 1000 %> => $1000
```

More Configs:

```
curr = {
  :priority        => 1,
  :iso_code        => "USD",
  :iso_numeric     => "840",
  :name            => "United States Dollar",
  :symbol          => "$",
  :subunit         => "Cent",
  :subunit_to_unit => 100,
  :separator       => ".",
  :delimiter       => ","
}


The pre-defined set of attributes includes:

:priority a numerical value you can use to sort/group the currency list
:iso_code the international 3-letter code as defined by the ISO 4217 standard
:iso_numeric the international 3-digit code as defined by the ISO 4217 standard
:name the currency name
:symbol the currency symbol (UTF-8 encoded)
:subunit the name of the fractional monetary unit
:subunit_to_unit the proportion between the unit and the subunit
:separator character between the whole and fraction amounts
:delimiter character between each thousands place
```

Answer (score 1):

you could define your own helper for what you are doing in `number_to_currency bill.total_amount, unit: '&euro;', separator: ',', delimiter: '.', format: '%n %u'`

```
def money value
  number_to_currency value, unit: '&euro;', separator: ',', delimiter: '.', format: '%n %u'
end
```

and use it like `<%= money(bill.total_amount) %>`